# Cocos2d-x how to prohibit game run in background

Tags: android, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have a cocos2d-x's game. When I press the 'home' button to quit the game, it closes the game but I don't want it to run in background. How can I do that?

Comment: To clarify things: you want your game to quit when pressing the Home button, *without* staying in the background, right?

Comment: yes. sorry, my english is poor. ;-)

Comment: can you help me to solve this problem? thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Into iOS (iphone) :

As per apple documentation, you should not quit application programmatically, But if you still want to quit app on some button's click event, than you should use following line.

```
 exit(0);
```

Comment: Sorry friend, but I am as iOS developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch it on the onPause() / onStop() method of the current Activity and pause the actual game right there.

Also, you can catch onResume() and resume the actual game if needed

Answer (score 0):

in your android activity,

```
@Override 
onStop(){ 
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); 
}
```

Comment: Isn't `CCDirector::sharedDirector() -> end()` needed before killing a process?

Comment: @LanceGray I guess you don't need to. since everything is sandboxed in Java Level, even there is Memory Leak in your c++ code, I guess it will be cleared when your process is killed. Not quite sure about it.